# TextToSpeech don't say number

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to use TextToSpeech (TTS) to say the percentage of battery and I wrote this code.

```
    myTts.speak("Battery percentage is "+batteryPercentage, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

Where batteryPercentage is inside an BroadcastReceiver

```
int batteryPercentage = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL,0);
```

When i run the application it says only Battery percentage is, without saying the number of percentage. Why? How can i fix?

Comment: Does `batteryPercentage` have a valid value?

Comment: I dont know if text to speech recognizes numerical characters but you could try to look for this as a jar or library to import http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/RuleBasedNumberFormat.html

Comment: @Andreas, yes batteryPercentage has a value like 45.

Comment: Is the line `myTts.speak(...)` in the same method as the other line? You're declaring `batteryPercentage` as a local variable, so if they're not, you're not looking at the same thing at all.

Comment: @MarioG. Did you find a solution for this? Did you try something else since you posted the question?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the BroadcastReceiver has not been called before, therefore the value of batteryPercentage might not have been set yet? Did you try setting it manually for testing?

Comment: The variable has a value the problem is that isn't enounced by the TTS